# Java-Stream - Collect a List of objects into a Set of Strings after applying Collector groupingBy

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors, groupingby

Given the following classes `Order` and `Item` and a list of `Order`s.

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Order {
    String customerName;
    List<Item> items;
}

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Item {
    long id;
    String name;
}
```

I need to create a map `Map<String,Set<String>> itemsByCustomerName` where keys are customer names from `Order` and a set of names of all `Item`s belonging to the customer name.

*Input example:*

```
List<Order> orders = List.of(
        new Order("John", List.of(new Item(1, "A"), new Item(2, "B"), new Item(3, "C"))),
        new Order("Alex", List.of(new Item(1, "A"), new Item(8, "H"), new Item(11, "K"))),
        new Order("John", List.of(new Item(1, "A"), new Item(6, "F"), new Item(7, "G"))),
        new Order("Alex", List.of(new Item(1, "A"), new Item(8, "H"), new Item(12, "L"))),
        new Order("Dave", List.of(new Item(24,"X"), new Item(25,"Y"), new Item(26, "Z"))));
```

the desired output would be

```
{Alex=[A, H, K, L], John=[A, B, C, F, G], Dave=[X, Y, Z]}
```

I have tried many ways including my last attempt below, but getting compile errors

```
Map<String, Set<String>> itemsByCustomerName =
    orders.stream().collect(groupingBy(
            Order::getCustomerName,
            mapping(order -> order.getItems().stream().map(Item::getName), toSet())));
```

*Error:*

```
Required type:
Map<String, Set<String>>
Provided:
Map<String, Set<Object>>

no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Stream<R> conforms to String inference variable T 
has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: String lower bounds: Stream<R81591>
```

How can I get instead of just a map of orders by name:

```
Map<String, List<Order>> ordersByName =
    orders.stream().collect(groupingBy(Order::getCustomerName));
```

to a `Map<String, Set<Item>>` or much better `Map<String, Set<String>>` with a set of item names?

So, my question is: how to convert a *list of orders* into a *set of item names* after applying `groupingBy`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were very close.

Since you need to transform a *stream element* **not** into a single object, but extract a *collection of items* from the *order*, you need a different *collector* - `flatMapping()` instead of `mapping()`.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> itemsByCustomerName =
    orders.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Order::getCustomerName,
        Collectors.flatMapping(order -> order.getItems().stream().map(Item::getName),
            Collectors.toSet())));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getCustomerName, Collectors.toSet())` should work in this case. The second parameter here is the collector used by groupingBy internally.